# Vim fastest way to select a block of text lines until a specific character

Tags: vim, macros

I have a page with some wikicode (tikiwiki) which includes html like such :

```
{DIV(class="Act PersonInterested")}
{HTML()}
  multiple 
  lines 
  of 
  html (svg) 
  code
{HTML}
{DIV}

{DIV(class="Act CHActivePFOnly")}
{HTML()}
  multiple 
  lines 
  of 
  html (svg) 
  code
{HTML}
{DIV}
```

I want with vim to delete the text between the {HTML()}{HTML} wiki tags. `dt{` doesn't work...

The most handy option I found is to record a macro, like that one :

```
qa   -> Records macro in register a
v/{  -> Visual selects text until next '{' symbol
q    -> Stops recording
@a   -> Applies macro from the current line
```

Then I move to the next line and reapply the macro with '@a' and so on until I finish to empty all the tags.

My question is, there must be somehow a faster approach, that I overlooked... Like a g: one or even simpler. I would be pleased to learn about it, and also, I didn't find much answers here or duckducking about that specific issue.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following would suffice

```
g/{HTML/,/{HTML/ d_
```

This assumes, as do the other answers, you don't have a `{HTML...` anywhere between your real tags. If you do, the only reliable way to do this is to use a parser.

**Breakdown**

```
g              : start a global command
/              : separator
{HTML          : search for {HTML
/              : separator
,/{HTML/       : set a range from the previous search result up until the next {HTML tag
d_             : delete to the empty register. As I have my clipboard synchronized with deletes, without the `_`, each delete goes to my windows clipboard slowing things down a lot in large files.
```

Comment: Thank you this did very efficiently the trick and cleaned all my files for further uses. Yes there are no ''{HTML'' stuff inside the part to delete, so this is great. The only downside is that it cleans everything at once, and for some cases an option to apply it only to the first matching occurrence might be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with:

```
:g/{HTML(/norm jd/HTML^M
```

or:

```
:g/{HTML(/norm jV/HTML^Mkd
```

if you are more confident with visual mode.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to obtain `^M`.

Answer (score 0):

did I understand the question right?

```
%s/{HTML()}\zs\_.\{-}\ze{HTML}//g
```

does the above command work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just record more complex macro ond then repeat it.

```
qa           -> Records macro in register a  
/{html()<cr> -> Find next   
j            -> Go down one line   
d/{html}<cr> -> delete to closing html tag  
q            -> Stops recording  
100@a        -> Applies macro 100 times or less if there is no matches
```